# Monitoring tool for Varnish

Tags: varnish

I have configured Varnish for my website and its working as site performance is excellent but does anybody know that there is any Varnish monitoring tool to see what content are getting stored in Varnish and what are hits & misses something similar to Memcached or APC monitoring tool.

Thanks,
-Nitin

Answer (score 3):

The `varnishhist` tool is also great for monitoring hits vs. misses and response time simultaneously. [This article](http://zygmund.net/varnishhist-what-does-it-tell-us/) gives a good overview of how to interpret the output since the manpage is pretty sparse.

Comment: Interesting. Your question is from 2014. I had used Nagios plugin on Opsview to monitor cache-hit ratio of varnish then.  I was using Varnish for web content. Now after so many years I have configured Varnish 6 and things have changed a lot. I am looking for a tool that will give me a wholistic data in a UI similar to AWstats like interface. Can't seem to find any. And this time I am using Varnish for OTT, and I can't believe what I am seeing in varnishstat.

Comment: You could try [Monitorix](https://www.monitorix.org/) which has the ability to monitor Varnish and graph the hits vs misses among other useful stats.

Answer (score 1):

To monitor Varnish, the most useful of the available tools directly available in Varnish is the command line `varnishstat` which gives you a detailed snapshot of Varnish’s current performance. It provides access to in-memory statistics such as cache hits and misses, resource consumption, threads created, and more.

If you add the `-1` flag, varnishstat will exit after printing the list one time.

To list specific metrics values, pass them with the -f flag:
e.g. `varnishstat -f field1,field2,field3`
For example: `varnishstat -f MAIN.cache_hit` will display a continuously updating count of the cache hits.

[Here is a series of articles](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/how-to-monitor-varnish/) with more details on how to monitor Varnish, what are the key metrics to watch, how to collect the metrics you want, etc...

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins for virtually any monitoring tool available. For instance Munin, Nagios or New Relic can easily be setup with varnish plugins. If you want to monitor it in realtime on the command line you have the `varnishstat` command that comes with varnish.